# How to get the Max date to calculate age?

Tags: mysql, sql

I am trying to calculate the age based on the recent date but when I used MAX function, it still returns all the dates

```
SELECT
   birth_date,
   sign_date,
   datediff(year, birth_date, Max(sign_date) - 
   CASE
      WHEN
         Datepart (dayofyear, birth_date) > Datepart(dayofyear, sign_date) 
      THEN
         1 
      ELSE
         0 
from
   customer_info inf 
   INNER JOIN
      table2 a 
      ON inf.id = a.id) 
GROUP BY
   inf.birth_date, a.sign_date
```

Comment: Why not use the current date?

Comment: no I have to use sign_date column

Comment: There isn't much point in using max() without a group by...

Comment: Do you need to display sign_date or just use it in the calculation?  If you don't need to display it remove it from select and group by.  Keep the Max(Sign_date) if you must.

Comment: get rid of MAX and just add a where clause, it may possibly work `WHERE a.sign_date = (SELECT MAX(a2.sign_date) FROM table2 a2 WHERE a2.ID = a.ID)` . Or just put the select into the `datediff()` function. The reason its not working is because you have a inner join so Max(sign_date) is just going to select the max date where the id's are equal not the max date in the table.

Comment: Is this mysql or oracle?  Not both

Comment: @K.Layton I tried your solution but still have the same results

Comment: @willardSolutions it’s mysql

Comment: @parfait I meant to tag someone else

Comment: Please edit tags and post actual, working SQL query without syntax issues.

Comment: @sisi my mistake if you want to just get the last date in the table remove the `WHERE a2.id = a.id` part but then you have to add it in your `Datediff()` function not the orginial query

Comment: @K.Layton dateiff is not accepting the select statement